# Await-ing a javascript event handler

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm struggling with an event handler in javascript, I'm trying to make things respond correctly with async / await.

The issue in the code below is with the `file.on` event-- I'm struggling to promisify it correctly.  Currently the `checkSomething` method returns before the `file.on` handler is finished, and so `returnValue` is always `false`.

I could use some advice and best practices.

What's a good way to go ensure  `returnValue` is checked / set in the handler before the value is returned?  I've tried putting the `await` keyword in front of the event handler, and in its callback function but that didn't work, and I'm basically scruffing along at this point and could use some tips.  Thanks.

```
const axios = require('axios')
const fs = require('fs')

/*....*/

let isItChecked = await checkSomething()

async function checkSomething() {
    let returnValue = false
    const response = await axios.get('https://someUrl.com', {
        responseType: 'stream'
    })

    const file = fs.createWriteStream('./localFile.txt')

    response.data.pipe(file)

    file.on('finish' () => {
        performATask().then((result) => {
            if (result == 'good') {
                returnValue = true  //need to make sure this is evaluated before returning
            }
        })
    })

    return returnValue
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, you just have to return a promise, which resolves after the execution reaches your desired point (where you have the comment).

Other things to keep in mind:

- Ensure you only use `await` from within `async` functions
- Use `===` instead of `==`
- End statements with `;`s

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs');

/*....*/

let isItChecked = await checkSomething();

async function checkSomething() {
  const response = await axios.get('https://someUrl.com', {responseType: 'stream'});

  const file = fs.createWriteStream('./localFile.txt');

  response.data.pipe(file);

  return new Promise(resolve =>
      file.on('finish', () =>
          performATask().then(result => resolve(result === 'good'))));
}
```

Comment: This is for my own edification, I noticed that he/she was using await outside of their async function as well.  Should the await that's being used in front of checkSomething() for the isItChecked variable be removed?

Comment: Depends on the omitted code. Perhaps that line is actually inside an `async` function. Otherwise, yes, using `await` is illegal and `isItChecked` could instead store the return promise directly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: @JonasWilms yes, but the result is within the callback of an event handler. `file.on()` does not return a promise.

Comment: @junvar Good point.  I was assuming this was a standalone function being returned within a larger async function.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @paoiherpoais yes, the line in question is indeed inside an async function, just omitted it for space.  And your suggestion worked great junvar, my sincere thanks.

Comment: @larryq Ah!  Okay that explains it.  Thanks.

Comment: @patrick but `performATask` does. The other answer does it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Since the event is only used as a signal for processing to continue, you can promisify and `await` its receipt before continuing with in-line style code. This also means that `result` need not be declared in outer scope of a nested fumction (which didn't work anyway due to being set asynchronously):

```
async function checkSomething() {
    const response = await axios.get('https://someUrl.com', {
        responseType: 'stream'
    });

    const file = fs.createWriteStream('./localFile.txt');
    response.data.pipe(file);
    await new Promise( resolve=> file.on(`finish`, resolve)); // wait here

    const result = await  performATask();
    return result == 'good`;
}
```